# How to programmatically change the Url based on a query string in Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

GridView generated into a table:

```
<table id="ctl00_centerContent_GridView1">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                <!-- COLUMN INFORMATION -->
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=908">Insurance 1</a></td> <!-- link color by default is blue and turns orange on hover -->
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=542">Insurance 2</a></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=587">Insurance 3</a></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=125">Insurance 4</a></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

How can I add a JQuery script which takes the url from each row and checks the `ccid` value and if it is either a `542` or `587`, then the link shouldn't be linked to anywhere and the font color should be black and the cursor should be default (arrow).

For example for the second row, `<a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=542">Insurance 2</a>` should be `<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: #000; cursor: default;">Insurance 2</a>`

Script (Started to write but need some help):

```
$("#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td").each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var cid = getParameterByName('ccid');
    /* HOW CAN I REPLACE THE URL OF THE ANCHOR to "javascript:void(0);" IF "cid" is 542 or 587? */
    $(this).closest('a').css('color', 'black'); //will this work?
    $(this).closest('a').css('cursor', 'default'); //will this work?
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

- How can I replace the Url of the anchor to `Javascript:void(0);` if
  `cid` is 542 or 587.
- How can I change the text color to black and the cursor to default
  arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an attribute using `.attr` (There's also no need for 2 calls to `.css`):

```
$(this).closest('a')
       .attr('href','javascript:void(0)')
       .css({color:'black',cursor:'default'});
```

---

Your code needs a few changes to do what you want, because currently its looking for the `ccid` variable in the *url of the current page* - not the url in the `href` attribute.

First off, change your `each` to be looking only at the `a` elements:

```
$("#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a").each(function() {
----------------------------------------^ here
```

Next, change your `getParameterByName` to take the url and the parameter you're looking for:

```
function getParameterByName(url, name) {
    console.log(url)
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results ? decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")) : "";
}
```

Finally, change your code to only perform the action originally specified in this answer if the `ccid` matches your requirement (note the removal of `closest('a')` as we're now only looking at `a` elements):

```
$("#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a").each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');
    if (cid == "542" || cid == "587"){
        $(this)
            .attr('href','javascript:void(0)')
            .css({color:'black',cursor:'default'});
    }
});
```

Live example below.

```js
$("#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a").each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');
    if (cid == "542" || cid == "587"){
        $(this)
         .attr('href','javascript:void(0)')
         .css({color:'black',cursor:'default'});
    }
});

function getParameterByName(url, name) {
    console.log(url)
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results ? decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")) : "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ctl00_centerContent_GridView1">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                <!-- COLUMN INFORMATION -->
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=908">Insurance 1</a></td> <!-- link color by default is blue and turns orange on hover -->
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=542">Insurance 2</a></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=587">Insurance 3</a></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="icard.aspx?cid=34&amp;cpid=345&amp;ccid=125">Insurance 4</a></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>908 as ave</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>Electronic</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">090-093-2311</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So `if (cid == "542" || cid == "587") { your code }`?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Your `cid` variable is being read from the *current url of the page* not the url in the href of that row. You need to change `getParameterByName` to look in the href of the link in that row and then what you suggest would work.

Comment: How can I use the Url of the href of the row instead?

Comment: I guess I can send the `url` variable I am using? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I get this error: `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
isearch.aspx, line 1 character 6` when I click on the link.

Comment: There was a `0` missing from `javascript:void(0)` in all my examples.

Comment: Yes! just noticed it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go in steps.

Iteration should be over `a` elements, as you do not have any irrelevant anchors, so good selector would be

```
#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a
```

To extract value of `ccid` something like that should work:

```
var ccidValue = getParameterByName($(this).attr("href"), "ccid");
```

Make sure to update `getParameterByName` to accept url parameter instead of working with current page url all the time:

```
function getParameterByName(url, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then check for the value to be "542" or "587", and do replace:

```
if (ccidValue === "542" || ccidValue === "587") {
    $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0);")
}
```

And if you want some styles applied, I really recommend defining a class and using it instead of some inline scripting:

```
disabledCardLink {cursor: default; color: black;}

$(this).addClass("disabledCardLink");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href*="ccid=542"]', 'a[href*="ccid=587"]').each(function(){
        DisableLink($(this));
    });
});

function DisableLink(elem){
    elem.parent().html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: #000;cursor: default;">' + elem.text() + '</a>');
}
```

Using the jquery 'Contains' selector to select all anchors that contain the ccids you looking for and passing each element to a method that replaces the html of its parent td element with the modified anchor tag.

Comment: Just a small note - the selector should be `$('a[href*="ccid=542"], a[href*="ccid=587"]')` otherwise it'll look for one within the other.

Comment: You are correct. I always do that wrong until I debug the problem.